# Java assign matches to variable

Tags: java, string

I am trying to do something like this but I doesnt seem to work

`String test = input.matches("[^a-zA-Z\\s]");`

I get an error saying `incompatible types`

Is there any way fixing this or any other methods?

***EDIT***

This is what I'm trying to achieve

Lets say i have this string

`String full = " This i$ an aaasdAr yeEeeAs oofo qwdsgy XY9 ";`

and i need to have the output as `$9`

this works but its a bit too messy

```
 for (int index = 0; index <= input.length() - 1; index ++)
            {
                if(String.valueOf(input.charAt(index)).matches("[^a-zA-Z\\s]"))
            {

            System.out.print(String.valueOf(input.charAt(index)));
            }
        }
```

Comment: `matches` returns a `boolean`, not a `String`.  Read the Javadoc.

Comment: In order to know how to "fix" your code, we'd need to know what you're trying to achieve. But if you look at the documentation for `matches`, you should be able to understand why your current code doesn't work.

Comment: It's still not clear *why* you'd have an output of "$9". You've given a single example, but no *description* of what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your specific problem, you can use [`String.replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), which takes a replacement regex:

```
String input = " This i$ an aaasdAr yeEeeAs oofo qwdsgy XY9 ";
String output = input.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z\\s]", "");
System.out.println(output);
```

This replaces everything that matches the regex with the empty string, and it prints `$9`.

Answer (score 4):

The method [matches](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) returns a boolean. As you are trying to assign that to a `String` instead, you're getting the compilation error.